# Deleting files and folders from a helix server while keeping them on the pc

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am new to perforce, i submittet my previous project to it as asked and added the p4ignore later. but now i dont want the files from the p4ignore like the .vscode folder on the server however when i try to mark for delete it also deletes them from my machine. how can i remove them on my server but keep them on the local machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the `p4 obliterate` command; this is used to permanently remove files from the server (including all their history), which will leave your local files in an untracked state.  Note that this requires `admin` level permission since file history is normally considered immutable.

If you can't get an admin to help with this, you can use the `p4 delete -k` command to open the files for delete while keeping the local files.  This is a little tricky because it still results in a deleted revision, and if you're not careful you might end up getting surprised at some point by having a sync operation delete your local files (e.g. a force sync may delete your local files to force them into agreement with the head depot revision even though they aren't on the client have list).

To avoid *that* potential problem, after you delete the files, exclude them from your client view.  That will not only prevent them from being added (similar to `.p4ignore`) but will also firmly exclude them from *any* operation that touches client files, including sync.  (I usually recommend using the client view to exclude files in the first place instead of p4ignore -- it has the advantage of being tracked on the server, and it also prevents you from syncing down "ignored" files submitted by other workspaces whose settings don't match yours.)

tl;dr: use `obliterate` for mistakenly added files if you can, otherwise use a combination of `delete -k` and client view tuning to make sure the depot and client files are hidden from each other.